# Extending Camel DSL

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route with a custom aggregator, it looks like this:
[image]

I would like to wrap the details so that developers can just add *a single line* to their routes to get the functionality. Can I wrap those lines so that I have a class that extends `ProcessorDefinition`, and then add that `ProcessorDefinition` to routes that need it, so that it looks like an extension of the DSL? If yes, is the `addOutput()` method the way to do this?

Something like this:

```
from("file:" + FILE_PATH + "?noop=true")
        .log("Detected file")
        .split().tokenize("\n")
        .streaming()
        .unmarshal(bindy)

        .addProcessorDefinition(new MyCustomAggregation())

        .to("direct:handleAggregatedRecords");
```

Where

```
MyCustomerAggegation extends ProcessorDefinition
```

Comment: Why would you want this?  For the sake of a one-liner, or is there some other custom logic that you're trying to encapsulate here?

Comment: Basically the latter... so that all the developers on the project don't need to know the details. For some use-cases, we have libraries that configure little direct routes that other developers can use, almost like a DSL extension. When i tried putting just those lines into a route of its own, it was complaining that it needed a destination.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar use-case and I don't think Camel has anything to offer out of the box to extend routes at a certain point with route fragments. **However, you can break apart one route into multiple fragments**

```
public abstract class ExtensibleRouterBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() {
      ProcessorDefinition<?> routeFragmentToExtend= from("file:" + FILE_PATH + "?noop=true")
        .log("Detected file")
        .split().tokenize("\n")
        .streaming()
        .unmarshal(bindy);

      configure(routeFragmentToExtend);

      routeFragmentToExtend.to("direct:handleAggregatedRecords");
  }

   //"Users" of your API can implement and extend your route
   public abstract void configure(ProcessorDefinition<?> from);

}
```

But this can get messy, especially if you have several **choice()** calls, so I wish Camel enhances it's API one day.

Answer (score 0):

To get a similar outcome, I use [Lombok @ExtensionMethod](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod) in the following way:

```java
@ExtensionMethod(MyRouteBuilder.Extensions.class)
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() {
    from("direct:in")
      .debugLog("Incoming message ${body}");
  }

  @UtilityClass
  public static class Extensions {
    public static ProcessorDefinition<?> debugLog(
        @NonNull ProcessorDefinition<?> route, String logMessage) {

      return route
          .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "debug-logger", logMessage);
    }
  }
}
```